# Облако для хранения фото с прямыми ссылками

Tags: сервер, хостинг, облако, веб-дизайн, облачное-хранилище

Нужно сохранить несколько картинок и фото в облаке с возможностью прямого доступа чтобы использовать в HTML тегах `<img src="" />`, с не ограниченым временем хранения и хорошим аптаймом ну и естественно бесплатно.

500МБ будет достаточно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внезапно, [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/).

Для каждой картинки можно получить статичную публичную ссылку, в которой нужно лишь заменить `www.dropbox.com` на `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`, чтобы вместо ссылки на страницу получить ссылку на сам файл изображения.