# Какой облачный сервис предоставляет прямые ссылки на картинки?

Tags: облако

Хочу подгружать фото в своем приложении Android.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 скорее всего вам подойдет.

**Обновлено:** ваш вопрос возможно дублирует следующий: [Облако для хранения фото с прямыми ссылками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/425610/195023)
Однако, можно поставить под сомнение его полезность в случае, если приложение станет популярно.